# How to reference Blogger post URL from within post

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

Short version:
How can I reference the URL of an individual post on Blogger from within the post? I know that I can use `<data:post.url/>` in the theme editor, but I haven't figured out a workaround to just get it at a random point in the post.

Long version:
The detailed situation is that some posts (which are automatically generated using Python from other data) have tables of contents, which link to individual items in the post. I could just use an internal link, as in:

(within the TOC)

```
<a href="#item4">4. Title of item 4.</a>
```

and then later

```
<div id="item4">4. Title of item 4.</div><p>Here's the info about item 4.</p>
```

As long as the IDs are unique between blog posts (which I can ensure), that almost works fine -- if I am looking at the post itself, the links are internal to the page and there's no problem, and if I'm looking at the main blog, the IDs are unique and the links are still internal to the page and fine.

But once I include a jump (so that the TOC is the only part that shows up on the main blog page, and to see more you need to go to the post itself), then the TOC links on the main blog page break because the links are no longer internal to the page (the link IDs are on the post, which is a different page). One easy solution would be to change the links in the TOC to include the post URL as in `<a href="http://blogname.blogspot.com/a/bunch/of/stuff.html#item4">`... but I don't have an automated way of doing that from the Python code that generates the HTML, since it doesn't know what the post URL will end up being.

One idea I have is to add some Javascript into the theme that re-writes the TOC links for me... so if someone has a solution along those lines, that would also be great.

Comment: interesting case, isnt it possible to set a custom url?

Comment: Yes it is, but it's an easy point of failure for the multiple (not all technically-savvy) members of the team who end up making posts -- it would be much better if I can make everything Just Work automatically.

Comment: I have come up with a partial Javascript solution: define each TOC entry as part of a class, and then in the theme template add some Javascript that uses document.querySelectorAll to find all of those elements and re-write them to include the post URL. My biggest problem now is simply finding the right place in the theme template to insert the code.